Horror film about a haunted house name?
A few years ago, I watched a horror film. I remember the movie title was "The Gates of Hell" (Probably American), but never found it.
Plot: The movie begins with an older couple that runs scared of their room, the spirits of the house started poltergeist activity. The house served as a little hotel (village), the new owner that runs the place it's aware of the paranormal activity.
She calls two guys that are paranormal researchers to investigate, one of them falls in love with the ghost of a blonde lady, that turns to be the ex wife of the mansion previous owner.
The previous owner was a weird guy with dark long hair, he was into witchcraft and weird stuff. One day the murders his wife, because he thought she was cheating him, then he sells his soul to the devil and kills himself. At the end when the paranormal guys get rid of the spirits, the owner of the house starts presenting symptoms of possession and ends on cliffhanger  
It was a really scary film, but I can't find it by name or description. That's everything I can remember from the film. 
It seems to be a horror film of the late 80's or mid 90's.
(It's not High Spirits... this is really a horror film, not a comedy)

Looks like a dupe of this question

Was this in English? If not, what language? What country was it produced in?

I have deleted the previous two iterations of this question because this one is more detailed. However, in the future please improve your existing question in order to get it reopened rather than just reasking an already closed question. You might also want to merge your multiple user accounts by following the procedure described here.

I recall seeing this film, but did not remember the name. As @robotik commented on a previous version of this question, the name of the film is High Spirits.  At the moment, the full movie can be found on YouTube easily

@faintsignal11 Hi! No, it's not High Spirits..this is really a horror film, not a comedy.

@Paulie_D Hi, I assume it's an American film. The name i remember was "Gates of hell" or "The gates of hell", but can't find it..

Okay, please stop deleting and reasking your question. If there is anything you would like to improve in your question, feel free to use the [edit] functionality.

Could it be this one? 
Paura nella città dei morti viventi (1980) aka "The Gates of Hell"
Full Movie: 



Welcome to the community. Could you please add text to your answer that explains why you think this is correct? Many people also use links to sites like IMDb to make responses more user friendly.
